# What was the new identity of the white slave in Kentucky ~1840, called the Boy John, after he was freed?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, slavery, book

In 1897, a book called ["The Boy John"](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Boy_John/d0sZAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) was published by a Kentucky lodge of the Order of Odd Fellows (a mutual benefit society with history going back to England), detailing the efforts of the lodge's members to track down and liberate the titular character, who was sold into slavery. After his liberation, the boy's whereabouts and identity is kept secret. Is the book based on real events, and if so - what was John's new identity?

If you want to read the book, you can find a copy [here](https://exploreuk.uky.edu/catalog/xt71ns0kst48?f%5Bsubject_topic_facet%5D%5B%5D=Independent+Order+of+Odd+Fellows.+Howard+Lodge%2C+No.+15+%28Shelbyville%2C+Ky.%29+--History.&per_page=20#page/1/mode/1up).

You can find the detailed summary of the book, along with all of my research [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MKIvVYDJO1O6hLBHxJq4fDdeoVUPzfpR9ejd7VWFaRE/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: I haven't read the book, but I know the Autobiography of Fredrick Douglass, which we have 0 legit reason to doubt in much of any way, was [often similarly attacked for seeming fictional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narrative_of_the_Life_of_Frederick_Douglass,_an_American_Slave#Reactions_to_the_text). We have ample evidence from the events of the last few years that truth is often much more outlandish than fiction could get away with, but I think inherently people just really really *want* to believe that slaves somehow on some level deserved it.

Comment: Also, I don't really have the patience to read all 42 paragraphs of this (I'm supposed to be on vacation), but it seems like the text here (what I skimmed) is asking a very different question than the title. If its even asking a question at all, that is (not sure it is).

Comment: To give an idea, the entire [Player's Guide for the Pathfinder "Strength of Thousands" campaign](https://downloads.paizo.com/Strength%20of%20Thousands%20Players%20Guide.pdf) (pdf) from Paizo (that I happen to have up in a tab right now) is only 35 paragraphs. 7 more than that seems a bit much just to ask a question.

Comment: @T.E.D. What on Earth are you talking about? "I think inherently people just really really want to believe that slaves somehow on some level deserved it." This is a reprehensible thing to say, and I have NEVER met anyone with such ideas. How on earth did this idea pop into your head reading this? I think you're projecting here.

Comment: @JimmyG. "I know this is long, and it used to be longer [...] However, I left the full question on this Google Doc" Thank you. However, this approach could be used to even more effect - you can condense the question to the basic theses for easier understanding, and leave the actual research linked and accessible for interested users. Your work is very impressive, but as-is - the sheer amount of text makes it easy to become confused about the actual question when looking over it, and that makes it harder to attract users who would be interested in the research.

Comment: I get that it's long but the question is simple, is the story true and if so what happened to John. The rest of this text is explaining what research I did and how and why it does not work, exactly like it says in this post: https://history.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask So why is this being closed. Nowhere do I find on this site something saying that posts that are too long will be closed. Please somebody help.

Comment: @JimmyG. Your latest edit removed some important context (for instance, the name of the book you refer to). I added the information I saw as relevant back in, feel free to roll back or further edit as needed.

Comment: I appreciate your help GREATLY. I have spent a lot of time on the question and really hope someone has answers. Again, your help is greatly appreciated.