# Is there any (other) record of white people being sold into slavery in America?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, slavery, newspapers

Awhile back [I asked a question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/69089/what-was-the-new-identity-of-the-white-slave-in-kentucky-1840-called-the-boy-j) about a book [*The Boy John: Story of a White Slave*](https://exploreuk.uky.edu/catalog/xt71ns0kst48?q=Lafferty+Hall&f%5Bformat%5D%5B%5D=books&f%5Bpub_date_sort%5D%5B%5D=1897&per_page=20#page/1/mode/1up/search/Lafferty+Hall) written in 1897. The book tells the story of a white boy who was sold into slavery. His master made him stay outside naked all day to tan him. Then, the story was found out by a lodge of [Oddfellows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odd_Fellows) who worked to have the boy freed. Read more in the linked question. I was basically asking if anyone had any more information on whether or not the story was real. No one has answered.

Then today, I was reading the first edition of [*The Emancipator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manumission_Intelligencier) and on the 16th page it relates the story of a man who was kidnapped, then cut with knives and had [aquafortis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitric_acid) poured into the wounds to scar him and darken his skin. They called it making him "merchantable", before being sold into slavery. He eventually escaped and the people who did it were let go on their words that it wouldn't happened again.

When I came across the Boy John, I was skeptical. That being said, I DID verify a significant number of details in the book. And, now, I come across a second story of it happening. I'm still skeptical. I don't know that scarring someone with Nitric Acid would darken their skin. So, the question is is there any record of white children being sold into slavery and passed off as an African slave in America? I am well aware about white slavery elsewhere. Also, to distinguish, I am not talking about indentured servitude. I am talking about being passed off as a black slave in America. My Google searches yield no results, but if I come across other mentions of it, I will update the question.

Oh, one thing that may be important, his father was white and his mother was American Indian, so his skin was probably already at least a little dark.

Comment: I think this is inadvertently getting into something interesting about US racial politics, where for everything else there are %s (so you can optionally call that part Native person "White", or get into their entire background with blood quantum and such), but where black people are concerned the [one drop rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-drop_rule) applies (probably because there was money involved).

Comment: This article can be read [here](https://digital.lib.utk.edu/collections/islandora/object/emancip%3A102#page/16/mode/2up). It is a second or third hand account from an anonymous letter to the editor, containing absolutely no verifiable details. You can see a later retelling of the same story [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=oBQ6srSuwowC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&dq=aqua%20fortis%20slave&pg=PA99#v=onepage&q=aqua%20fortis%20slave&f=false), with a bit of variation in the details, but in this one the free man enslaved was descended from a slave.

Comment: @justCal, why do you believe that is the same story retold, and not just a story of another incident, as some of the details of don't mesh. For example, the guy died in the forest in the second story; whereas, he was reunited with his friends in the first. Further, the second story has him hide in the woods, whereas the first, he goes directly to his friends. Also, in the first story, the man's wife died the night he was kidnapped, but the second story has the man's wife and children still alive. Am I missing something?

Comment: Whoa, I just Googled nitric acid burns, it definitely has the potential to darken the skin, so long as it is diluted enough to not eat the skin away down to the meat. [Check this out](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/The-nitric-acid-burn-trauma-of-the-skin.-Kolios-Striepling/f9f6351eaa75a3ae47a6f3eb3f360044eb6e67d4/figure/2).

Comment: Both have brother in law selling his brother (brother vs brother popular Christian theme), both stories related at abolition convention, both relate being told the story  by the person who witnessed the man, use of aqua fortis in both, final lines in both utilize similar ending phrases: ***'Such is the abominable sin and inequity of slavery'*** and ***'This is the condition of a man that has one drop of African blood in his veins, in the United States of America'***

Comment: And both lack any real details which could be verified...

Comment: The first story is his half-brother who sells him, but your point is taken. The first was not an abolitionist convention, but was *allegedly* written by someone with first-hand knowledge of the account. But again, point taken on their bias. If nitric acid was actually used in this manner, I would expect it to be repeated. As for the final statements being similar, they sound like the end of EVERY anti-slavery screed. Not saying you are wrong, these are just counterpoints that popped into my head. I'll do some searching for aqua fortis in newspapers.